# Appcelerator erro: Unable to locate cli executable

Tags: node.js

Estou usando o OSX El Capitain e acabei de baixar o Appcelerator Studio. Depois de instalar eu tentei rodar, e quando eu tento fazer log in eu recebo esta mensagem de erro: Unable to locate CLI executable (print da tela abaixo). Eu já instalei o NodeJs baixado diretamente do site do Appcelerator.

Alguém sabe como resolver?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respondendo minha própria pergunta:

O problema é a permissão da pasta `/usr/local/bin`. Ao alterar as permissões desta pasta para que meu usuário possa acessar resolveu o problema.